# Angular apply cycle order

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application. Some of the data which is being changed effects the view after the apply cycle. I want to do some stuff after the apply cycle is completed.

Is there a way to do this? Call some function after the apply cycle is completed?

IS there a way to make sure that one watch will be called before another?

Comment: show us the code that you have. Could probably implement something in the success callback.

Answer (score 1):

To run code after the $digest cycle, use $timeout:

```
$timeout(function() {
   ... run code here ...
});
```

$timeout will automatically trigger an $apply after the code is executed, and after the view has been rendered.

As to your second question - I don't think its possible to reliably ensure $watches are handled in a particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) method. Also it might be achieved using [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) with `invokeApply` set as false.

It's hard to say without seeing a context.